# Display SQL query result in a label in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, executescalar

I'm trying to display the SQL query result in a label but it's not showing. This is my code:

```
     string result = "SELECT ACTIVE FROM [dbo].[test] WHERE ID = '" + ID.Text + "' ";
     SqlCommand showresult = new SqlCommand(result, conn);
     conn.Open();
     showresult.ExecuteNonQuery();
     string actresult = ((string)showresult.ExecuteScalar());
     ResultLabel.Text = actresult;
     conn.Close();
```

Need help please. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Is your query actually returning data? If so I would'nt recommend to use (string) first receive the data as it comes int, double, etc and then when you assign it to the label do myVariable.ToString();

Comment: Yes, query is returning data. i've tried to use int and byte and still not working.

Comment: which data type does the Active column has?

Answer (score 9):

Try this one.

```
   string result = "SELECT ACTIVE FROM [dbo].[test] WHERE ID = '" + ID.Text + "' ";
   SqlCommand showresult = new SqlCommand(result, conn);
   conn.Open();
   ResultLabel.Text = showresult.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
   conn.Close();
```

Comment: Please do not concatenate your query as string. Using parameters with the `SqlCommand` prevents sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo in there? You have two calls to the database:

```
showresult.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This won't return a value and I'm not sure why you would have it there

```
string actresult = ((string)shresult.ExecuteScalar());
```

Unless you have a shresult variable, this query should error. What is the shresult variable?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SqlParameter` to filter the result and call `ExecuteScalar()` or `ExecuteReader()` method.

```
 string result = "SELECT ACTIVE FROM [dbo].[test] WHERE ID=@ID";
 SqlCommand showresult = new SqlCommand(result, conn);
 // If ID is int type
 showresult.Parameters.Add("@ID",SqlDbType.Int).Value=ID.Txt; 

 // If ID is Varchar then 
 //showresult.Parameters.Add("@ID",SqlDbType.VarChar,10).Value=ID.Txt; 

  conn.Open();
  string actresult = (string)showresult.ExecuteScalar(); 
  conn.Close();
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actresult))
       ResultLabel.Text = actresult;
  else
       ResultLabel.Text="Not found";
```

Comment: this will result in an exception...shresult is not declared

Comment: @CCBlackburn - Thanks! I've just copied text from OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string result = "SELECT ACTIVE FROM [dbo].[test] WHERE ID = @id";
    SqlCommand showresult = new SqlCommand(result, conn);
    showresult.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", ID.Text);

    conn.Open();
    ResultLabel.Text = showresult.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    conn.Close();
}
```

This will dispose the connection and has no string concatenation in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 conn.Open(); 
 string result = "SELECT ACTIVE FROM test WHERE ID = '" + ID.Text + "' ";
 SqlCommand showresult = new SqlCommand(result, conn);

 showresult.ExecuteNonQuery();
 int actresult = ((int)showresult.ExecuteScalar());
 ResultLabel.Text = actresult.Tostring();
 conn.Close();
```

Comment: Please see the OP's Comment he had tried int but it didnt solve it