# What is the right way to load the values from the database to label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

### Admin.aspx

```
       <div id="valueIntroduction" class="labelarea" runat="server">   </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
```

### Admin.aspx.cs

```
        SqlConnection NewConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SoicConnection"].ConnectionString);
        NewConn.Open();
        SqlCommand NewComm = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCommand NewComm1 = new SqlCommand();

        if (Department.Items[0].Selected)
        {
                firstPanel.Visible = true;
                myLegend.InnerText = "Informatics";
                NewComm.CommandText = "getTextHeaderINFO";

                NewComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                NewComm.Connection = NewConn;
                NewComm.CommandTimeout = 3000;
                SqlDataReader results = NewComm.ExecuteReader();

                while (results.Read())
                {
                     Response.Write(results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString());
                     Label valueIntroduction = results["TEXT_CONTENT"];
                }

         }
```

What I am exactly tryting is to get the value from database and loading it into a label. I am new to .net and stackoverflow. Sorry incase if I dont know how to use this forum properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `SqlDataReader results = NewComm.ExecuteSclar();`

Instead of  `SqlDataReader results = NewComm.ExecuteReader();`

And set the label text to the result.

```
   ResultLabel.Text = NewComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
   conn.Close();
```

Here is a smililar queston
[Display SQL query result in a label in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813112/display-sql-query-result-in-a-label-in-asp-net)

### Edit

For the first record

```
 int counter=0;
 while (results.Read())
 {
     if(counter++=0)
     {
          ResultLabel.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
          conn.Close();
          break;
     }

 }
```

Comment: **What I am exactly tryting is to get the value from database and loading it into a label.** Kindly read this line

Comment: Shekar here by default it is taking the last value of the fetched record. Incase if I want to get the first record to the label what should I do?

Comment: @vimal since you expect single value then you must modify your query accordingly. Because you need only a single record and you are fetching multiple record from the database.

Comment: @vimal for the first record I am modifying my answer.

Comment: Ya shekhar i got the answer for this question