# I got and SQL select syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I want to find the number of rows in the table data urunAd but I get an error like this

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'urunAd='.

```
OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Urunler WHERE urunAd= " + tbAd.Text + "", baglan);
```

and also - How do I present the results in my ASP.Net?

Comment: Always use parameterized queries, as it is your query is vulnerable for sql-injection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are assigning text. You should add `''` around the text:

```
OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Urunler WHERE urunAd='" + tbAd.Text + "'", baglan);
```

but instead of doing so - **use [parameterized queries](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Parameterized-Queries-ADO.Net.aspx)**: *(here is a short example)*

```
using (OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Urunler WHERE urunAd=@value", connection))
{
    komut.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", tbAd.Text);
    /* execute the query... */
}
```

For presenting the results in your ASP.Net a quick search on google along the line of "how to present result from sql command in asp.net" gave quite a few results. [Among them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813112/display-sql-query-result-in-a-label-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new :)